# Splitting numbers according to digit position

Tags: r, split, digits

I am trying to create a `new` variable, which would store 2nd, 3rd and 4th and the last three digits  of each number of `tx`. For example the first number in `tx` would be 812500 in `new`

I did this

```
tx<-c(4812129004534500, 6430650557835, 579900098554, 382183224511777, 49057595473648551, 64951444098766, 649544543781, 87567909876421)
new <- sapply(tx, function(x) substring(x, first=c(2,3,4), last=3))
```

but the output is undesirable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gsub()` with the regex-pattern below will work..

What is does:

It selects the parts between `()`-braces as groups.
 - The first group is digits 2, 3 and 4
 - The second group is the last three digits
It then replaces everything with group1 + group2

```
gsub( "^\\d(\\d{3}).*(\\d{3}$)", "\\1\\2", tx )
[1] "812500" "430835" "799554" "821777" "905552" "495766" "495781" "756421"
```

Comment: ahh nice one...was about to post `sub(".{2}(.{3}).*(.{3}$)", "\\1\\2", tx)`

Comment: @RonakShah finally... at last I'm faster than you. Had to wait about a year for that ;-)

Comment: @Wimpel thanks.. how would it change if the first group contained digits 12, 13, 14?

Comment: @Julia How would/could you know that the first digit is `12`, and not `1`  and `2` for the second digit?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
as.numeric(paste0(substr(tx, 2, 4), substr(tx, (nchar(tx)-2), nchar(tx))))
#[1] 812500 430835 799554 821777 905552 495766 495781 756421
```

A variation of the above can be (as pointed out by @jay.sf),

```
as.numeric(paste0(substr(tx, 2, 4), substring(tx, nchar(tx) - 2)))
```